# Google Maps: How to add numbered or lettered markers?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a simple way to add numbered gmarkers onto a map? Much like how maps.google.com plots them as A-Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Maps API Icon Maker](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/mapiconmaker/1.1/) is an open source utility that has an option to create labeled markers (as well as use a custom color and size).

Comment: Here's the link to the wizard, which will give you an idea of its capabilities: http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/mapiconmaker/1.1/examples/markericonoptions-wizard.html