# How to add labels on Google Maps Pinpoints?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

Creating a google map with store locations within 50 miles of user entered address. Have map & pinpoints showing correctly but all of the pinpoints just have a dot on them. I'd like to be able to label them A, B, C, D, etc so that I can list out locations & addresses in sidebar.

How would I do this? Here's the code I'm using to add my pinpoints.

```
    var point = new GLatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var marker = new GMarker(point);
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                map.openInfoWindowHtml(point, myHtml);
            });
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343575/google-maps-how-to-add-numbered-or-lettered-markers/2343612#2343612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent, thanks. Included this js library.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library/

And then all I needed to do was update the

```
var marker = new GMarker(point);
```

to this

```
var newIcon = MapIconMaker.createLabeledMarkerIcon({label: "A", primaryColor: "#FD766A"});
var marker = new GMarker(point, {icon: newIcon});
```